# Odoo 9 report Task error

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want create report from Project > Task.

When try load data from table **account_analytic_line**

[image]

get this error

"'project.task' object has no attribute 'timesheets_ids'" while evaluating
'doc.timesheets_ids'

```
    <tbody>
                        <t t-foreach="doc.timesheets_ids" t-as="l">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                   <span t-field="l.name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-field="l.name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                   <span t-field="l.name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-field="l.name"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                    </tbody>

<template id="report_task">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="project.report_task_document"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Any solution?

Comment: Check your spell it timesheet_ids .., I think so

Comment: @VigneshwaranThenraj  Tnx a lot of....add answer I will mark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its timesheet_ids not timesheets_ids. Just a spell mistake.